# JAX-RS with jersey return encoded string for Urdu/Arabic Text

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I have a simple REST service in JAVA ( JAX_RX ). I have to return some Urdu/Arabic works to client (that is webpage for my case). On client side, I am getting utf-8 encoded strings. I have to show original string.

Below is class information with sample query that I have to return.
**Class **

```
@Path("/book")
public class Book {

    @GET
    @Path("/query")
    public Response getParams(
            @QueryParam("url") String url,
            @QueryParam("text") String text) throws IOException
    {
        if ( url != null)
        {
            return Response.status(200).entity("Given URL: " + url).build();
        }
        else if ( text != null )
        {
        return Response.status(200).entity ( new String( "گدھا" ) ).build();
        }
        return Response.status(200).entity("Invalid format !!!").build();

    }
}
```

When I query from front-end `http://localhost:8080/WSdemo/book/query?text=%DA%86%DB%8C%D8%A6%D8%B1`, I get this output `Ú¯Ø¯Ú¾Ø§`. That is encoded utf-8. How to get original text `"گدھا"`

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare your endpoint as follow, specifying the character encoding you want:

```
@GET
@Path("/query")
@Produces("text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
public Response getParams(..) {..}
```

Or I guess you could set the encoding on the Response

```
return Response.status(200)
    .header("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
    .entity(text)
    .build();
```